# Relay uses initial variable during setVariables transition, not "last" variable

Tags: relayjs

I have a page where a bunch of file ids get loaded from localStorage, then when the component mounts / receives new props, it calls `setVariables`. While this works and the new variables are set, the results from the initial variables is used during the transition, which causes an odd flickering result.

Why would Relay give me something different during the transition at all? My expectation would be that `this.props.viewer.files.hits` would be the same as the previous call while `setVariables` is doing its thing, not the result from using the initial variables.

```
const enhance = compose(
  lifecycle({
    componentDidMount() {
      const { files, relay } = this.props
      if (files.length) {
        relay.setVariables(getCartFilterVariables(files))
      }
    },
  }),
  shouldUpdate((props, nextProps) => {
    if (props.files.length !== nextProps.files.length && nextProps.files.length) {
      props.relay.setVariables(getCartFilterVariables(nextProps.files))
    }

    return true
  })
)

export { CartPage }

export default Relay.createContainer(
  connect(state => state.cart)(enhance(CartPage)), {
    initialVariables: {
      first: 20,
      offset: 0,
      filters: {},
      getFiles: false,
      sort: '',
    },
    fragments: {
      viewer: () => Relay.QL`
        fragment on Root {
          summary {
            aggregations(filters: $filters) {
              project__project_id {
                buckets {
                  case_count
                  doc_count
                  file_size
                  key
                }
              }
              fs { value }
            }
          }
          files {
            hits(first: $first, offset: $offset, filters: $filters, sort: $sort) {
              ${FileTable.getFragment('hits')}
            }
          }
        }
      `,
    },
  }
)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Ah I finally figured this out. `prepareParams` was changing the value

```
export const prepareViewerParams = (params, { location: { query } }) => ({
  offset: parseIntParam(query.offset, 0),
  first: parseIntParam(query.first, 20),
  filters: parseJsonParam(query.filters, null), <-- setting filters variable
  sort: query.sort || '',
})


const CartRoute = h(Route, {
  path: '/cart',
  component: CartPage,
  prepareParams: prepareViewerParams, <--updating variable
  queries: viewerQuery,
})
```